# Updating Angular and CLI causes: Incompatible peer dependencies found

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to update angular using `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`, I get the following error:

> Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to
> "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 ||
> 7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "10.1.6").
> Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/localize" @ "^10.0.0".
> Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0"
> (extended), would install "10.1.6").
> Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta
> <8.0.0" (extended), would install "10.1.6").
> Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^8.0.0"
> (extended), would install "10.1.6").
> Package "tsickle" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "~3.3.1", would install "4.0.3").
> Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.2.16"
> (extended), would install "10.1.6"). Incompatible peer dependencies
> found. See above.

What is the meaning of `incompatible peer dependency`?

How to fix each one of these requirements?

Comment: It means the peer dependencies, i.e. the things your dependencies rely on you to also install, aren't compatible with one another. It then lists what it means specifically, e.g. codelyzer wants at most Angular 7, but you're installing 10. So you need to update your other dependencies too, not just the angular components.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the great explanation, so I will update each one of those.

Answer (score 4):

try
`ng update codelyzer` first, then
`ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`, and `ng update @angular/material` if it's need

Answer (score 4):

If you encounter `Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler"` please run `ng update codelyzer@latest`. This will update it in the `package.json`.

Thereafter you can run `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` ( For updating to Anguar 11 ) again. In my case this worked well.